# Destroy one session on same domain

Tags: session

I have domain with two folders foo/test and foo/test2 with a different pojects.
I start session on both projects 
for test

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['usernameTest']='user';
```

for test2

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['usernameTest2']='user2';
```

and on logout i destroy session.

```
session_destroy();
```

Problem is when i destroy session on one project session gets destroyed on other one two.
How can i point out which session to destroy?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The session is bound to a cookie (see [documentation for PHP session handling](http://php.net/manual/intro.session.php)). The cookie is by default set to the domain of your site, and the root path `/`. You can set your own path via the `session.cookie_path` setting before any of the session_* function.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_path', '/foobar1');
```